# Delete a list item element with Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I made a simple form that takes an input name and when I click submit, it will append the output name into an unordered list with a delete button beside each item. But when I click the delete (X) button, it still leave the X button there, and when I have multiple list, it remove all the list instead of the list that corresponds with each item.

[image: view]
[image: view1]

```js
$("button#submit").click((e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let name = $("#name").val();
  console.log(name);
  $("ul#submittedName").append(
    "<div class='container'><div class='row'><div class='col-sm'><li id='nameList'>" +
    name +
    "</div><div class='col-sm'><a class='delete' href='#'>X</a></div></div></div></li>"
  );
  $("#name").val("");
});

$("ul").on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
  $("li#nameList").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<form id="formName" class="align-center p-3 mx-auto">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" />
  </div>
  <button id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Submit
      </button>
</form>
<ul id="submittedName" class="align-center p-3 mx-auto"></ul>
```

Comment: You cannot have more than one element with any given  `id`, **it must at all times be uniqe per-document**.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Do what? Also, `li` can only be a child of `ul` or `ol`, not of `div`. `ul` can only have `li` children. Your HTML is highly invalid. I suggest you take care of that before diving into jQuery (which is obsolete in 2022 anyway, learn JS and DOM).

Comment: Just a note: you're appending `<div>` elements inside of an `<ul>`, but only `<li>` are allowed as direct children of an unordered list.

Comment: @connexo jQuery _isn't_ obsolete in 2022. Millions of sites around the world still use it, and devs being brought in to managing those sites still need to use it.

Comment: 100% of devs I know had to deal with jQuery was for a single purpose the past 5 years: To get rid of any jQuery in existing code bases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, id's are meant to be unique, but you can do this without the use of the id at all, and since you want to remove the delete button as well, just get the ancestor `div.container` and remove it, this will remove the `li` and the delete button:

```
$("ul").on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
   $(this).closest('div.container').remove();
});
```

If you fix your HTML to be complient, all you need to do is, `$(this).closest('li').remove()` in your event handler. Here is an HTML complient example for what you are trying to do

```js
    $(function(){
        $("button#submit").click((e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            let name = $("#name").val();
      
            $("ul#submittedName").append("<li>" + name + "&nbsp;<a class='delete' href='#'>X</a></li>");
            $("#name").val("");
        });

        $("ul").on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
            $(this).closest('li').remove();
        });
  });
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <form id="formName" class="align-center p-3 mx-auto">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" />
      </div>
      <button id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Submit
       </button>
    </form>
    <ul id="submittedName" class="align-center p-3 mx-auto"></ul>
```